# AABB in Frustum Defined by 8 corners

Tags: c++

It seems like every example I can find has to do with using DirectX or OpenGL and it is confusing the snot out of me... I am not using either of these so i do not have any sort of view or clipping matrix.

I have a view frustum shaped element(i have the 8 corner coordinates) and i need to see if an axis aligned box is intersecting it.

Could someone please post a quick snippet with comments?

Comment: "so i do not have any sort of view or clipping matrix." If you aren't using matrices with some kind of software renderer, then what _are_ you using?

Comment: Creating a plugin for another piece of software that does not provide anything other then the frustum corners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look for AABB culling in *World Space*.  If you have the 8 corner coordinates of the frustum shaped element, you can construct the 6 planes of the view frustum.  From there you can determine the various cases where the box intersects the frustum (or not), not to forget the case where the box totally encloses it, or where it is totally inside of it.

Here's an ancient article from ye olde flipcode that explains things a little.  You can google on from there to find other articles:

http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Frustum_Culling.shtml